# TypeScript – what is 'export import'?

Tags: typescript, obsolete

[Apparently](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/a8e13a9837ee), you can say 'export import xx = module("xx")' in TypeScript.

But what does that mean? I didn't see that in the spec.

Comment: This question concerns syntax that was removed from TypeScript about 4 years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good observation.

This is a composition technique that makes the entire imported module act like an external module created within the enclosing module. Here is a shortened example:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass {
        doSomething() {

        }
    }
}

declare module EnclosingModule {
    export import x = module(MyModule);
}

var y = new EnclosingModule.x.MyClass();
```

The export keyword on its own makes a module an external module. In this case, it is making `MyModule` an external module of the enclosing module even though it isn't originally defined inside of the enclosing module.

Why?

I guess this is a handy way of re-using modules rather than repeating them in different contexts - making them accessible in more than one place where it seems logical to do so.

Comment: It's interesting that section 9.2.2 of the spec states "It is not possible to export a module identifier declared in an import declaration." Unless I'm getting my terminology wrong, isn't that what we're doing above?

Comment: It doesn't work out of the box like this - but you can use it in definitions. i.e. `declare module SomeModule { export import stuff = module("stuff");  }`

Comment: NB. For anyone else stumbling on this now (like me), I can save you some time: this is purely historical and no longer appears in the example linked to by OP. Also `import x = module` became `import x = require`. (Was `module(MyModule)` ever valid? Not that it matters now...)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker indeed - back in 2012 we would have been using version 0.8 of TypeScript and the syntax was quite different.

Answer (score 4):

As of 0.8.1.1, you apparently need to use this syntax when you're exporting classes that extend classes declared in other modules.

For instance, in 0.8.1, you could say this:

```
import mUiBase = module("../UiBase");

export class BaseViewModel extends mUiBase.UiBase {
}
```

But in 0.8.1.1, that gives you an error "Exported class extends class from private module", so you need to do this instead:

```
export import mUiBase = module("../UiBase");

export class BaseViewModel extends mUiBase.UiBase {
}
```

Presumably that's intended, and not just a bug.

Comment: My understanding from the discussion on CodePlex (can't find link at this moment...) is that this is a bug, and export import is a temporary workaround.

Comment: I was using 0.8.1.1 ... Just upgraded to 0.8.3 and all my "export import" are now errors (can simply remove the export). So JcFx was right about it being a bug. Strange that Steve described a real use for this, what with that now?